# Matching braces code doesn't terminate

Tags: scala, parsing

I have this code below to check a string. We want to verify that it starts with '{' and ends with '}' and that it contains sequences of non-"{}" characters and strings that also have this property.

```
import util.parsing.combinator._

class Comp extends RegexParsers with PackratParsers {
  lazy val bracefree: PackratParser[String] = """[^{}]*""".r ^^ {
    case a => a
  }

  lazy val matching: PackratParser[String] = (
    "{" ~ rep(bracefree | matching) ~ "}") ^^ {
      case a ~ b ~ c => a + b.mkString("") + c
    }
}

object Brackets extends Comp {
  def main(args: Array[String])= {
    println(parseAll(matching, "{ foo  {hello 3 } {}}").get)
  }
}
```

The desired output for this is to echo `{ foo  {hello 3 } {}}`, but it ends up taking a long time before dying from `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. What am I doing wrong and what should I have done instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression for bracefree string matches even an empty string, so parser produced by `rep()` succeeds without consuming any input and will loop endlessly.

Use a `+` quantifier instead of `*`:

```
lazy val bracefree: PackratParser[String] = """[^{}]+""".r ^^ {
  case a => a
}
```

Also, by default `RegexParsers` will skip empty strings and whitespaces. To turn that behavior off, just override method `skipWhitespace` to always return `false`. In the end your parser will look like this:

```
 import util.parsing.combinator._

 class Comp extends RegexParsers with PackratParsers {
   override def skipWhitespace = false

   lazy val bracefree: PackratParser[String] = """[^{}]+""".r ^^ {
     case a => a
   }

   lazy val matching: PackratParser[String] = (
     "{" ~ rep(bracefree | matching) ~ "}") ^^ {
     case a ~ b ~ c => a + b.mkString("") + c
   }
}

object Brackets extends Comp {
  def main(args: Array[String])= {
    println(parseAll(matching, "{ foo  {hello 3 } {}}").get)
    // prints: { foo  {hello 3 } {}}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the termination problem, but now when I run it it prints `{foo  {hello 3 }{}}` instead of `{ foo {hello 3 }{}}`. For my use case, that doesn't break anything, but it still counts as a bug.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider yes, it's a default behaviour of `RegexParsers`. I've updated my answer with solution for that.